# Is it possible to mount an encrypted disk image so that only current user is able to access it?

Tags: disk-utility, encryption, filevault, disk-volume

I use [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/) to mount an encrypted volume. When the volume is mounted, other admin users are not able to access it:

```
admin1 %
admin1 % su - admin2
admin2 % ls /Users/admin1/veracrypt_mounted
admin2 % ls: /Users/admin1/veracrypt_mounted: Permission denied
```

I'm considering switching to an encrypted disk image (created via Disk Utility and using the sparse bundle format), to avoid the dependency on VeraCrypt and macFUSE. Filesystem portability is not needed.
However, during my tests, when I mount the image its contents are also accessible to other root/admin users.

Is it possible to mount the disk image so that only my user is able to access it, and no other root/admin user?

- Why I need this: this is a shared laptop with many admin users.
- System: Monterrey 12.13.1 on M1

Comment: How does the Veracrypt protection work, what is the result of `ls -ld  /Users/admin1/veracrypt_mounted`?

Comment: Does VeraCrypt prevent access when admin2 becomes the root user by either entering the `sudo su` command or the `sudo -i -u root` command? Also, what happens when admin2 enters the command `sudo ls /Users/admin1/veracrypt_mounted`?

Comment: This is going to be very hard (/impossible) in general, because another admin/root user can *become* you (e.g. via `sudo -u admin1`).

Comment: @GordonDavisson  Running the command with sudo reveals the contents :facepalm: Because macFUSE is a combination of kernel extensions + FUSE user processes I hoped it worked better, but it's accessible anyway. It seems there is no (easy?) way to mount an encrypted volume for single-user access.

Comment: @DavidAnderson see my comment above, thanks.

Comment: I think you'll just have to remember to put it away after use.